# Let $M$ be the set of all $m\times n$ matrices over real numbers.Which of the following is true??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be the set of all $m\times n$ matrices over real numbers.Which of the following statements  is/are true??

1. There exists $A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb R)$ such that the dimension of the nullspace of $A $ is $2$.
2. There exists $A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb R)$ such that the dimension of the nullspace of $A $ is $0$.
3. There exists $A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb R)$ and $B\in M_{5\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ such that $AB$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.
4. There exists $A\in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb R)$ whose null space is $\{ (p,q,r,s,t)\in \mathbb R^5 | p=q, r=s=t\}$.

I am sure about the option $3$ definitely will not come. But I don't know about others..and then the dimension of the nullspace is $3$??

Comment: Do you know the dimension theorem? Btw, 3 is true.

Comment: yes ..dim v= Rank v + Nullity v

Comment: but how it is true

Comment: What is $\dim V $ here? What's the rank at most? So, nullity is at least ... ?

Comment: dim $V$ is 5 and rank is 2 and nullity is 3

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you at dantopa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **option $1$** and **option $2$**,

$A=(a_{ij})_{2 \times 5},\qquad \forall a_{ij} \in\mathbb{R}$

So rank of $A$ is almost $2$.

Also we know that **nullity of $A\quad = \quad$column nullity of $A$**

So nullity of $A$ is at least $3$.

For **option $3$**,

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}_{2 \times 5} \in M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb{R})$

$B=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0   \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}_{5 \times 2} \in M_{5\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

$AB=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}=I_{2\times 2}$

For **option $4$**,

Let $N(T)=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in \mathbb{R^5}:x_1=x_2, x_3=x_4=x_5 \}$

$=\{(x_1,x_1,x_3,x_3,x_3)\in \mathbb{R^5}: \forall x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \}$

$=\{(x_1,x_1,0,0,0)+(0,0,x_3,x_3,x_3): \forall x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \}$

$=\{x_1(1,1,0,0,0)+x_3(0,0,1,1,1): \forall x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Basis of $N(T)$, $\quad B_{N(T)}=\{(1,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,1,1)\}$.

So dim$(N(T))=2$

So Nullity of $T = 2$ but nullity of $A$ is at least $3$.

Therefore $N(T)$ is not Null space of $A\in  M_{2\times 5}(\mathbb{R})$.

So only **option $3$ is correct**.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:
Apply the dimension theorem. What is the maximal rank of a $2\times 5$ matrix?
3. does hold: take e.g. $B=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0}$ and $A=B^T$.

Comment: sorry sir I didn't get ...can you please explain detail

Comment: maximal rank is 2

Comment: Then, the minimal nullity is $3$. This rules out 1, 2 and also 4 after determining its dimension.